# Insert Multiple Data PHP Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, import, laravel-excel

I am working on a script where I have to upload excel sheets and upload records to the backend and store it to Firebase Realtime Database. My script is working fine for under 200 records but for a large number of records it takes long time. Do you know how to store multiple data at the same time using Firebase?

Here is the code what I am using.

```
public function import(Request $request) {
    // Validation
    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,txt,xls,xlsx'
    ]);

    // Excel File
    $file = $request->file('file');

    $fileArray = Excel::toArray([], $file);

    dd($fileArray);

    $i = 0;
    $successCount = 0;

    $counter = $this->database->getReference('counter')->getValue();
    $formatted_value = sprintf("%04d", $counter['customer']);
    $date=getdate(date("U"));

    foreach($fileArray[0] as $x => $val) {
        $customers = collect();
        if($i != 0) {
            // Validasi Nama Customer (Duplicate)
            $bNameLow = strtolower($val[0]);
            $bNameTrim = ucwords($bNameLow);
            $customer = $this->database->getReference($this->tableCustomer)->orderByChild('business_name')->equalTo($bNameTrim)->getValue();

            if(!$customer) {
                $customers->push([
                    'added_date' => sprintf("%02d", $date['mday']).'.'.sprintf("%02d", $date['mon']).'.'.$date['year'],
                    'address' => '-',
                    'business_name' => $bNameTrim,
                    'business_phone' => empty($val[11]) ? "-" : $val[11],
                    'branch' => '-',
                    'company' => Session::get('company'),
                    'cp_email' => '-',
                    'cp_name' => empty($val[43]) ? "-" : $val[43],
                    'cp_phone' => empty($val[12]) ? "-" : $val[12],
                    'latitude' => '-',
                    'longitude' => '-',
                    'notes' => '-',
                    'priority' => 'High',
                    'status' => 'New',
                    'type' => 'Customer',
                    'deleteable' => 'true',
                    'custId' => 'CUST'.$formatted_value,
                ]);

                $postRef = $this->database->getReference($this->tableCustomer)->push($customers[0]);

                if($postRef){
                    $successCount++;
                }

                $formatted_value = sprintf("%04d", $formatted_value+1);
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }

    if($successCount != 0){
        $updateData = [
            'customer' => $counter['customer']+$successCount,
        ];

        $res_update = $this->database->getReference('counter')->update($updateData);

        if($res_update) {
            return redirect('customers')->with('status', 'Customer Import Success');
        } else {
            return redirect('customers')->with('status', 'Customer Import Failed');
        }
    
    } else {
        return redirect('customers')->with('status', 'Customer Import Failed');
    }   
}
```

Thanks